# Trying to reverse a string and getting a bus error

Tags: c++

I am trying to reverse a string (but that's not the problem that I have). The problem is trying to change the value of the string array given a certain index. However, every time I try to change the value at the index, I get a bus error. Namely, `Bus error: 10`. I'm not sure what this means. Also, I tried `str[0] = "a"` but this also gives me a bus error. Any suggestions to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

void reverse(char* str){
    str[0] = 'a'; 

}


int main(){

    char* str = "hello"; 
    reverse(str); 

}
```

Comment: The answer is the same as the answer to this one, just recently asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816473 but also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075049

Comment: String literals are constants and can not be modified.

Comment: Also: The compiler should give you a warning that your code is not valid.  See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef79aa4884d08883

Comment: `str[0] = "a";` should definitely not even compile. How did it give you a runtime error?

Comment: You should also get errors for `str[0] = "a"`. If you don't then you really need to turn up your compiler's diagnostic level.

Comment: @MobyDisk it's nothing to do with the first one you linked

Comment: @chris common compilers give "warning" in their default mode for conversion from pointer to integer

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Both the Clang and GCC on Coliru give errors with no warning options. I don't recall seeing compilers give warnings for that except in C mode.

Comment: Note the code above has `str[0] = 'a'`, not `"a"`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The similarity is that the first link shows code declaring a string literal without const.

Comment: @MobyDisk That's where the similarity ends though, the main thing about this question is writing to the string literal, which doesn't happen in the other one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this line should atleast give you a warning:

```
char* str = "hello";
```

you are converting a string constant to a pointer, which is not allowed.
To fix your code, you should use, `char str[] = "hello"` in `main()`.

When you pass this array in `reverse()`, it decays to `char*`, now the question which you asked in previous answer's comment.

> But when I write cout << str << endl;, why does it print out "hello"? Shouldn't it print only the first character of the string since it points to the first element of the array?

It is because the `<<` operator on `std::cout` is overloaded. If you give it a `char*` or `const char*`, it treats the operand as a pointer to (the first character of) a C-style string, and prints the contents of that string:

```
const char * str= "hello";
cout << str; // prints "hello"
```

If you give it a char value, it prints that value as a character:

```
cout << *str;   // prints "h"
cout << str[0]; // prints "h"
```

Answer (score 6):

Allocate your string as an array on the stack and not as a pointer into a possibly read-only segment of your program.

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

Comment: I have one question, void reverse(char* str){}, am I passing a pointer or is * acting as a reference?

Comment: In C++, arrays "decay" into pointers in certain contexts. Here, the pointer argument to `reverse` starts out as a pointer to the first element of the array in `main`.

Comment: But when I write cout << str << endl;, why does it print out "hello"? Shouldn't it print only the first character of the string since it points to the first element of the array?

Comment: The type of `str` in `reverse` is pointer to `char`, which is treated by `std::cout` as a string. In contrast, plain `char` is a single character.